# Main method returns if submethod has stopped by return in C#

Tags: c#, methods

Say I have two EventHandlers:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do first stuffs

   button2_click(sender, e);

   //Do second stuffs
}

private void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do something

   if(myCondition) return; //Also return in button1_click

   //Do something else
}
```

Is there any way to return in `button1_click` and skip `//Do second stuffs` part if `button2_click` has stopped with return?

I'm looking for a way other than using a public `bool` variable to check if `myCondition` in `button2_click` is `true`

Comment: B should return a boolean. Then A simply has if(B()) { doMoreStuff(); }

Comment: @AnthonyPegram what if instead of B, we have a event handler like `button1_click()` ?

Comment: A, a function not tied to an event, is calling an event handler (B), is that what you mean? Don't do that. Extract the body of your event handler to a different method. Have your event handler and A each call the extracted B, which can now have a useful return value.

Comment: you can use out parameters

Comment: My recommendation is the same. Extract the meaningful code from at least the second handler, but probably both. The meaningful code should be one (or more) functions, each of which can have a useful return value.

Comment: Agreed With @AnthonyPegram: refactor your relevant functionality to an outside method, and call that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to extract the meaningful portions of each handler into methods that can be called independently and can have useful return values. This is particularly important for your second button's handler, since the handler for button1 also depends on it.

Upon extracting the code, you can transform the extracted method into a boolean function, and can depend upon the return value to continue your process.

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ThingToDoForButton1();
}

private void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ThingToDoForButton2();
}

private void ThingToDoForButton1()
{
    // do something 

    if (ThingToDoForButton2())
    {
         // do something else
    }
}

private bool ThingToDoForButton2()
{
    //Do something

    if(/* some condition */) return false; 

    //Do something else

    return true;
}
```

Of course, it is up to you to provide meaningful names for your methods, once extracted, and to consider breaking down your code into additional smaller functions if the "do something" and "do something else" parts are not insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want something like this

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do first stuffs

    button2_click(sender, e);

    //Reading the tag value of sender object that is assigned in that case
    if (!(bool)(sender as Button).Tag)
        return;
    //Do second stuffs
}

private void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
    //Since sender object is button1 in the example
    Button button = sender as Button;

    button.Tag = true;

    if (myCondition)
    {
        button.Tag = false;
        return;
    }//Also return in button1_click

    //Do somthing else
}
```

Comment: The question specifically said "other than using a public bool variable"

Comment: @BenVoigt, sorry I forgot to point his notion. In that case he can assign the tag value to read it. I am updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CancelEventArgs Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do first stuffs
    var e1 = new CancelEventArgs();
    button2_click(sender, e1);
    if(e1.Cancel) 
    {
       return;
    }
   //Do second stuffs
}

private void button2_click(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   //Do somthing

   if(myCondition)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
      return; 
   }

   //Do somthing else
}
```